# What is the npapi-msdocs plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, javascript

What is the [npapi-msdocs](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-msdocs/) plugin?

Is it possible with use this plugin to handle Microsoft Office documents in Chrome?
For example to view a .doc file inline instead of having to downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what npapi-msocs is meant for. Pretty neat idea. Just download the .dll and move it to your plugins folder.

Comment: Where is chrome plugins folder exactly?